# Is there a way to create Generic DAO class for Room Persistence Library

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am using [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) and I am trying to  avoid boilerplate code by creating a Generic DAO class, like this

```
@Dao
public interface PendingTaskDao<V>  {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM :tableName")
    Maybe<List<V>> getAllEntitiesFrom(String tableName);
}
```

But the compiler complains `<table or subquery> expected got : tableName`. Is there a way to create Generic DAO, or the library must work that way in order to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: You can probably build your own implementation, but what you want is not supported out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, it is obvious that I have to copy paste a lot :D

Comment: When that comes up, first question you have to ask yourself is "why do I _actually_ need so many identical queries". It's not a good design for apps to materialize the whole table dataset into their memory, you probably made design error somewhere.

Comment: In fact you are right, I will have just two :D, but  DAOs will the same except the names of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*the library must work that way in order to prevent SQL injection*, yes, you're right.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query.html) of `@Query`:

> This query is verified at **compile time** by Room to ensure that it compiles fine against the database.

So to let the query compile correctly, you must provide a tableName, not as a parameter, but directly in the query, hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

Though, you cannot create a generic DAO for all the operations for all the entities, you can at least create a BaseDao to commonize the `insert`, `insertAll`, `update`, `updateAll`, `delete`, and `deleteAll` operations.

```
/**
 * Created by Yousuf Sohail on 10/7/18.
 */
interface BaseDao<T> {

    /**
     * Insert an object or array of objects in the database.
     *
     * @param obj the objects to be inserted.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(vararg obj: T): LongArray

    /**
     * Update an object or array of objects from the database.
     *
     * @param obj the object to be updated
     */
    @Update
    fun update(vararg obj: T)

    /**
     * Delete an object or array of objects from the database
     *
     * @param obj the object to be deleted
     */
    @Delete
    fun delete(vararg obj: T)
}
```

`select` and `selectAll` will go to specific Daos of entities.